# RESTful API cursor pagination with total count

Tags: json, rest, pagination, api-design

I'm designing a RESTful API, returns result with pagination and total number.
Here is my approach

**Endpoint**

`[GET] /items`

**Parameters**

| Parameter | Description |
| --- | --- |
| before_cursor | Return results before cursor |
| after_cursor | Return results after cursor |
| limit | Limit of result |

**Response**

```
{
  "items": [
    ...
  ],
  "pagination": {
    "prev_cursor": string, // cursor before the range, for backward navigation
    "next_cursor": string, // cursor after the range, for forward navigation
    "total": number, // total number of items
    "total_before": number, // item count before prev_cursor helps client positioning
    "total_after": number // item count before next_cursor helps client positioning
  }
}
```

**Example**

Raw data

`Item_0, Item_1, ... Item_99`

Get first page

[GET] /items?limit=10

```
{
  "items": [item_0, ..., item_9],
  "pagination": {
    "next_cursor": "item_10",
    "total": 100,
    "total_before": 0,
    "total_after": 90
  }
}
```

Navigate to next page

[GET] /items?limit=10&after_cursor=item_10

```
{
  "items": [item_10, ..., item_19],
  "pagination": {
    "before_cursor": "item_9",
    "next_cursor": "item_20",
    "total": 100,
    "total_before": 10,
    "total_after": 80
  }
}
```

Navigate back to previous page

[GET] /items?limit=10&before_cursor=item_9

```
{
  "items": [item_0, ..., item_9],
  "pagination": {
    "next_cursor": "item_10",
    "total": 100,
    "total_before": 0,
    "total_after": 90
  }
}
```

Is it a good approach? Or is there a neater way to design API for this requirement?

Comment: Recommended reading: https://web.archive.org/web/20180905061056/https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/timelines/guides/working-with-timelines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to design this endpoint with a rest approach. I found these 2 the best when you need to deal with collections.

**Approach 1**

```
GET /items?page=2 & page_size=10
```

This should return only 10 elements from your resource items and skip the first page (it is up to you to decide if you start your collection with a 0 or with 1)

A response should look like this

**Response 1:**

```
[
  item1,
  item2,
  ...
  item10
]
```

Response Header: `RecordCount` or `X-Total-Count = 530`

The total count in this case is included in the headers.
Now if the user wants to paginate the next page or the previous they can do the following request:

- next: `GET /items?page=3 & page_size=10`
- previous: `GET /items?page=1 & page_size=10`

Including this request as part of the payload and trying to comply with Rest for [HATEOAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS) is what I think can be the second approach

**Response 2:**

```
{
   TotalCount=530,
   Result:
   [
      item1,
      item2,
      ...
      item10
    ],
    Next: '/items?page=3 & page_size=10'
    Previous: 'GET /items?page=1 & page_size=10'
}
```

In this case, the total count is included in the response and the items on the result and you build the next and previous URLs